# Arangement of six circles in a plane

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Six circles (including their circumferences and interiors) are arranged in the plane so that no one of them contains the center of another. Prove that they [the six circles] cannot have a point in common.

This should be solved by application of pigeonhole principle. Don't have the right idea.

Comment: Why shouldn't they? Place them in pairs of two separate from each other such that the distance between the centers of each pair is (slightly) larger than the radius ($O\!\!O$)

Comment: No, no, I dont arrange. For any arrangement with such described property, it should be proven they dont have a point in comon.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood the meaning of "a point in common" as a pairwise property.

Comment: ITs not that clear, thats ok.

Comment: I took the freedom to edit some clarification in.

Comment: Could you clarify that point in your question? I also read "common point" as pairwise

Comment: thanks, it should be corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_i$ denote the $i$-th ball. Assume $P$ to be one particular point satisfying
$$P \in \bigcap_{i=1}^6 B_i$$
Then since $P\in B_i \quad\forall\ i$, we must have that the centers, call them $m_i$ lie within $B_P$, the ball of the same radius around $P$.
Now we take the balls of half radius $B'_i$ and apply the pigeonhole principle to six circles of radius $\frac r2$ (the $B'_i$) inside a circle of radius $r$ ($B_P$) and the constraint that no $B'_i$ may touch another.

Comment: Hmmm, you are assuming they are all same r?

Comment: I think I will have to look at this tomorrow... Maybe I misunderstood altogether the problem...

Comment: @VividD WLOG you can do that (take the maximum radius of all $B_i$ to find a "greater freedom" in the position of $m_i$ for those with smaller initial radius)

Comment: Ok, now I see...

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I will upvote your answer tomorrow, because I already used all votes for today (I think 30 is limit)... All best.